# What is the proper way to externally validate clusters when I have only a sample of the dataset labeled, but want to cluster the entire dataset?

Tags: clustering, dataset, validation, unsupervised-learning, methodology

I have a dataset of text-based documents that I want to cluster. For a sample of this dataset (~10%) I have manually annotated labels (i.e., the ground truth). I would like to cluster this dataset to "automate" the annotation of the remainder of dataset. I see two options for this:

1. Cluster the entire dataset. Select the clustering algorithm, number of clusters, other parameters by maximizing an external cluster validation index (e.g., ARI) on the labeled sample, thus assuming if the produced clusters conform with the manual labels, the clusters for the unlabeled data should be similarly composed (similar idea of a cluster for this data).
2. Cluster the labeled sample only. Select the algorithm and other methodological details by maximizing an external cluster validation index. Then, use that method for the entire dataset and select algorithm parameters, number of clusters using a mix of internal validation indices and qualitative review.

Does one of these methods pass the sniff test? I haven't seen this exact use case yet but I'm sure it's happened. My inclination is that number 1 makes the most sense, but can't decide if this would potentially overfit to the sample data.

Comment: The option that’s dismissed too readily is to label more data.

Comment: Fair enough - to clarify, the assumption is that this is not currently possible.

Comment: Let's think somewhat philosophically. Say your whole N cases is a population and the n-cases subsample (which true labels you created) is a sample. A sample may be somewhat "distorted", biased relative a population; so a natural penchant would be to cluster a population rather than a sample. Now a question. When doing the labelling job on that n-cases sample, might you have been affected by the (potential) bias/peculiarity of the sample? That is, if you could label the entire N, would that change your labelling among the n? Yes or not? If not, I would suggest clustering of the N, not the n.

Comment: Else speaking, if your done labelling is _true_, error-free, i.e., it is just a selection from the totality of N-sized true classification, then it looks reasonable to try to approximate the classes by a clustering procedure on the level of the totality. I.e., cluster N data. But if you are considering your done labelling as just an _alternative clustering_ (with its potential reaction to a sample bias), then perhaps it is better to cluster only the n.